# Return record from table 1 even if table 2 has no matching record

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database

I've only just begun learning SQL so please bear with me if this is a really basic question, but here is what I'm trying to do.

I am writing a query to return the history of an individual device. I'm pulling from three different tables, one that lists the serial numbers of each device (Nodes), one that lists whether or not each device was online on a daily basis (Node Status), and a third that lists when the location of each device has changed (Location Status).

I would like to pull every record from the Node Status table, and *if* there is a record in the Location Status table I want to bring that over as well. The query below will return the information as I want it but only if there is a matching record of a change in both tables.

```
        [Node Status].Online, Nodes.[Node Serial Number], [Node Status].Gateway,
        [Node Status].[Date Verified], [Node Location Status].[Location ID], 
        [Node Location Status].[Install/Remove], [Node Location Status].[Date of Action]
    FROM
        (Nodes 
    INNER JOIN 
        [Node Status] ON Nodes.NodeID = [Node Status].[Node Serial])
    INNER JOIN 
        [Node Location Status] ON (Nodes.NodeID = [Node Location Status].[Node Serial Number]) 
                               AND ([Node Status].[Date Verified] = [Node Location Status].[Date of Action])
    WHERE 
        ((Nodes.[Node Serial Number]) = [Enter node serial number]);
```

*Note: Many of you have suggested LEFT JOIN, which seems like the right answer, but it looks like I left out an important bit of info. I am writing this within Access and it apparently does not support LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result

Comment: Also tag your question with the db you are using

Comment: That's what the outer join is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I would suggest the following:

```
select
    ns.online,
    n.[node serial number],
    ns.gateway,
    ns.[date verified],
    nls.[location id],
    nls.[install/remove],
    nls.[date of action]
from
    (
        nodes n inner join [node status] ns on 
        n.nodeid = ns.[node serial]
    )
    left join [node location status] nls on
    ns.[node serial] = nls.[node serial number] and 
    ns.[date verified] = nls.[date of action]
where
    n.[node serial number] = [Enter node serial number]
```

Given that the user is specifying the Serial Number from the `Nodes` table and you state that you want to view **all** entries in the `Node Status` table, it makes sense that this should be an `inner join`, with a `left join` to the `Node Location Status` table to return nulls where a value does not exist.

Note that the aliases `n`, `ns`, & `nls` are purely to save some typing.

I'm not sure why you think that MS Access does not support a `left join`, as it definitely does!

Comment: This did the trick, thanks so much for the help. 

I tried to recreate the error that was making me think ```left join``` was not supported but couldn't, so I must have been making some other strange error.

Answer (score 1):

You want `LEFT JOIN` if you want to keep the rows in one table, even when there are no matches in the other tables.

Because you want all rows in `[Node Status]` that should be the first table.  All subsequent joins should then be `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT ns.Online, n.[Node Serial Number], ns.Gateway,
       ns.[Date Verified], nls.[Location ID], 
       nls.[Install/Remove], nls.[Date of Action]
FROM [Node Status] ns LEFT JOIN
     Nodes n
     ON n.NodeID = ns.[Node Serial] LEFT JOIN
     [Node Location Status] nls
     ON n.NodeID = nls.[Node Serial Number] AND
        ns.[Date Verified] = nls.[Date of Action])
WHERE n.[Node Serial Number]) = [Enter node serial number];
```

Note that I removed the extraneous parentheses from the `FROM` clause and added table aliases.  Both so the query is easier to read.

EDIT:

MS Access does not support "normal" SQL syntax.  You have to tweak it a bit:

```
SELECT ns.Online, n.[Node Serial Number], ns.Gateway,
       ns.[Date Verified], nls.[Location ID], 
       nls.[Install/Remove], nls.[Date of Action]
FROM ([Node Status] as ns LEFT JOIN
      Nodes as n
      ON n.NodeID = ns.[Node Serial]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     [Node Location Status] as nls
     ON n.NodeID = nls.[Node Serial Number] AND
        ns.[Date Verified] = nls.[Date of Action])
WHERE n.[Node Serial Number]) = [Enter node serial number];
```

Comment: This is a really well communicated answer and looks like the solution, though Access doesn't allow LEFT JOIN. That's my fault for not including that info, I didn't realize it was relevant. Sorry for that, but I wanted to make sure I thank you for the great answer.

Comment: @taffyhound . . . Of course MS Access supports `LEFT JOIN`.  But it has some other syntax weirdnesses.  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `left join` meaning if you get your desired o/p somewhere around the inner join replace it with `left join`

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. You will get all record from main table 'Nodes' along with tha matching rows of other tables